# Object detection or image classification? Each image has 3 shapes. I want to return 1 if they are all triangles, 0 otherwise

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, object-detection

Question is in the title. Every image has three shapes, which can be either triangles or squares. I want to return 1 if all shapes are triangles, 0 otherwise. Which do you think would work better for this problem, framing this as an image classification problem or an object detection problem?

Answer (score 0):

Object detection will suit you better.

Image classification is a machine learning based form of computer vision in which a model is trained to categorize images based on the primary subject matter they contain.

Object detection goes further than this to classify individual objects within the image, and to return the coordinates of a bounding box that indicates the object's location.

So you can return 1 if no of triangles (this no is given by the object detection model in the form of bounding box) in the image equals 3 and 0 otherwise.